# PayFlow Pro and line item reporting

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I have a client who processes payments through the PayPal PayFlow Pro gateway.

Most of the transactions come in via the website, and we log the transactions and provide reporting in the site's admin tools.

However, the client sometimes logs directly into the virtual terminal to add manual transactions and issue refunds. So the transaction log on the site does not necessarily reflect the actual state of transactions sent through the gateway.

Additionally, there are several product categories which the client would like to perform reporting on—and because the site's transaction log is inaccurate, they want to do this reporting in the virtual terminal.

The solution for this was to create a separate account per category and send the transactions per category to it's appropriate account.

My co-worker's less-than-ideal implementation was to disallow them from adding items from more than one category to the cart at one time. The user was instructed to do two separate checkouts.

This was barely tolerable when there were only two categories, but now there will be three.

The client's proposed solution is to start allowing them to mix categories in the cart, but on the back end, split them out and send separate transactions per category "inline" during checkout.

As you can probably guess, I am not a fan of doing it this way. I'm worried about the possibility of something going wrong halfway through the process and leaving the checkout in a half finished state. Plus, it sounds like an accounting nightmare.

I was hoping that PayFlow Pro would provide some sort of "line item" functionality and provide the appropriate reporting capabiilties.

Their XML API seems to support line items, and I'm assuming this is for Level III transactions. However, when I log into the virtual terminal, there doesn't seem to be any support for Level III data. Plus, I get the feeling this isn't Level III is meant for, and that I'm "going against the grain".

So I'm weighing my options here, and these are the two I've considered so far:

- Provide functionality to create ad-hoc transactions, issue refunds, etc. in our web app, and make a rule that they can only make these changes through the web app. That way we can log these transactions and provide more accurate reporting on our end. However, this will be a ton of work.
- Perhaps there's something else in the PayPal universe that provides a richer API and reporting capabilities on the backend. It would need to be able to support their existing merchant account. If their fees went up it would be a reasonable tradeoff for getting what they want.

Generally, asking if anyone understands PayPal well enough to tell me if option B exists, because PayPal's product offerings are very confusing to me. Additionally, if anyone has any general advice, or if there's an option C I haven't considered.

Thanks.